# Why are JavaScript strings immutable?

Tags: javascript

I understand that they *are* immutable, but I want to know *why* they are immutable.

Is there any specific reason as to why JavaScript strings are immutable? Wouldn't it make life easier if they weren't, just like arrays?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/

Comment: Read the `Immutability in JavaScript in Practice` and `What About Performance?` sections